# In a PN junction diode, why is the extension of the implant much smaller than the one of the substrate?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Here is a typical example of illustration of a PN junction. The substrate is here of type N. The implant is of type P. This is called a P in N junction.

(it could have been the opposite, with a N in P junction : the substrate would be the P, the implant would be the N)

So the question is : in a PN junction diode, why is the extension of the implant much smaller than the one of the substrate ? Why not taking the same size : half the width for P, half the width for N ?

[image]

Comment: Several reasons. First, the substrate is doped as it is grown, so there is no thickness limit of that doping (and all 200mm wafers and up are all p-type nowadays). Second, the implant will be in the near surface region because, well, that is a limitation of the ion implant process - the ions only go so deep. Finally, the exciting bits are right around the interface (the depletion region) so there is no reason whatsoever to make things 50:50 at all.

Comment: Your drawing isn't even to scale. The substrate might be on the order of 1 mm thick, while the implant region might be a few microns or 10's of microns.